# Django fail to use data from setting.ini [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, django

When I set in setting.py the folowing paramters 
EMAIL_HOST ,EMAIL_PORT , EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD EMAIL_USE_TLS,  DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

And call send_mail every thing works fine but,
when I move does paramters to setting.iniI I get error.
I am able to see does param correct in my code when I try to view them:

```
raise Exception('EMAIL_HOST ->   ' + settings.EMAIL_HOST +
                    'EMAIL_PORT ->   ' + str(settings.EMAIL_PORT) +
                    'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ->   ' + 
settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD +
                    'EMAIL_HOST_USER ->   ' + settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER +
                    'EMAIL_USE_TLS ->   ' + str(settings.EMAIL_USE_TLS)
                    )
```

But when I try to send mail I get the folowing error

```
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any suggestion Why when I use does paramters in setting.py it works fine 
and when I put then in setting.ini I am able to see them but fail to send mail ,what am I doing wrong?

I use:
Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.5.0
and I call send_mail as folow

```
send_mail("this is the subject",
         "this is the content", settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ["eran3216@gmail.com","eran3216@gmail.com"])
```

Thanks
for the help

Comment: post the full traceback..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote in the ini 'string' 
with qouts when I remove them it worked, so stuiped from me
so instread of EMAIL_HOST='aaa'
need just 
EMAIL_HOST=aaa